# ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE returns differently encoded spliced Uri parts

Tags: android, android-storage

I want to set a writable directory in my Android app. When the user select prefered directory, the returned data is made in two parts: Left-one displays correctly (with column, slashes and spaces), while the other is encoded with %3A, %2F...  After that, it all goes wrong as the system grants permissions for this bad Uri. Why is it that way? Is it normal?

In Activity A:

```
btnSetPath.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                    intent.addFlags(FLAG_DIR_SUPPORTS_CREATE);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 41);
                }
```

in onActivityResult:

```
if (requestCode == 41 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK&& Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
                 ) {

             if (data != null) {
                 Uri retourUri =data.getData();
                 Log.i(TAG, "Retour direct Uri: " + retourUri.toString());

                 int takeFlags = data.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                         | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                 getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(retourUri, takeFlags);
             }
         }
```

How come my trace output is:

Retour direct Uri: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3Adocuments%2FTest%20%2FMovies%2FAsyncam

Comment: ` the returned data is made in two parts: ` Where are you talking about? You only get one uri.

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                   
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);` That has no effect at all. Better remove as it is confucing code.

Comment: `intent.addFlags(FLAG_DIR_SUPPORTS_CREATE);` I have never seen that. Does it have effect?

Comment: See on the last two lines of the question, that is my trace output. You have a non-encoded part: " content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary", then an encoded part: "%3Adocuments%2FTest%20%2FMovies%2FAsyncam"

Comment: That is a completely normal content scheme. Dont worry. Have a look at uri.getPath() to see it different.

Comment: `How come my trace output is: ` Strange formulation. You mean uri.toString().

Comment: @greenapps: The FLAG_DIR_SUPPORTS_CREATE, I did had it because later on I try to DocumentsContract.createDocument(...), but documentation says about 2nd argument:   parentDocumentUri  Uri: directory with FLAG_DIR_SUPPORTS_CREATE

Comment: `it all goes wrong as the system grants permissions for this bad Uri.` What goes wrong?

Comment: @greenapps: When I try to do this, with retrived permissions taken from a list:                 Uri newFile  = DocumentsContract.createDocument(getContentResolver(),     mesPerms.get(a).getUri(),"video/mp4","myFileName");

Comment: I get this trace: 10-20 15:04:24.063 1644-1644/com.xxx.xxxx W/Documents: Failed to create document     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3Adocuments%2FTest%20%2FMovies%2FAsyncam

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157163/discussion-between-syl-or-and-greenapps).

Comment: `m‌​esPerms.get(a).getUr‌​i()` We cannot see how you messed around with that uri in the mean time.

Comment: Directly taken from content resolver, no messing.              List<UriPermission> mesPerms =  getContentResolver().getPersistedUriPermissions();

Comment: I never used that function before. No IllegalArgumentException but return value == null and file not created. I wonder where this flag DocumentsContract.Document.FLAG_DIR_SUPPORTS_CREATE comes in play. (How can you use it without a class name?).With DocumentFile i can create a file in that directory.

Comment: I do not get that flag selecting a dir with OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.